# Single row UPDATE query in SQL takes more than 3 seconds

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, ubuntu

```
UPDATE `productData`.`productList`
    SET  `dateLastUpdated` = CURDATE(), 
         `totalReviews` = 100
    WHERE `productList`.`name` = 'FirstchefproUltraSharpDualJuliennePeelerVegetablePeelerStainless';
```

This query takes 2.93 seconds and only affects a single row.

The table is ~75k rows long. I don't have much experience in SQL, is there a better way to do this? Updating a single row shouldn't take this long

I'm using the latest version of SQL on an Ubuntu server

If you need any more information just ask and I'll add it to the post.

Thanks

Edit:

I actually didn't know that SQL and mysql where different things.

The select statement

```
SELECT *
FROM `productList`
WHERE `productList`.`name` = 'FirstchefproUltraSharpDualJuliennePeelerVegetablePeelerStainless';
```

takes 2.88 seconds, so I guess its a problem with my index.

EDIT:

Thankyou for your help

When I try to create an index on name it says this:

```
ERROR 1170 (42000): BLOB/TEXT column 'name' used in key specification without a key length
```

EDIT:

switched name to a varchar(64)

its much faster now

Thanks everyone

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? This looks like mysql?

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server.  And how long does a select using that where clause take?

Comment: I not a mysql guru but I suspect you don't have a covering index for that query so it causes a table scan.

Comment: Is the table properly indexed on name?

Comment: That is also a long key.

Comment: the name field is an ideal candidate for an index.

Comment: I feel the `name` field will take benefit from FULLTEXT index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Either create an index on the `name` column (as written in some comments), or
2. use an indexed column in the `WHERE` statement, e.g. the product ID if your table contains something like that.

Answer (score 1):

For this query:

```
UPDATE `productData`.`productList`
    SET  `dateLastUpdated` = CURDATE(), 
         `totalReviews` = 100
    WHERE `productList`.`name` = 'FirstchefproUltraSharpDualJuliennePeelerVegetablePeelerStainless';
```

You want an index on `productList(name)`:

```
create index idx_productData_productList on productData(productList);
```

Comment: Why an index on `productList.name` would not be beneficial? Here `productList` is the table name I believe.

Answer (score -1):

Create an index on

```
`productList`.`name`
```